# QGIS: print composer legend layer order management trouble

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping

In the print composer I cannot change the order of items displayed in the legend: the buttons "Bring up/down items" seems not working: after doing their task for few times, suddenly instead of moving the selected layer they just highlight the upper/lower layer.
Can anybody please help me understand what it's going wrong and how to solve the problem on
QGIS 3.28.8?

[image]

Comment: Because the arrows are here to order the layers, not the categories inside a layer. If you need to reorder the categories, you need to do that in the layer properties.